# Hello world with gitlab ce docker container running on local ubuntu

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab

I would like to run the docker image for gitlab community edition locally on my ubuntu laptop.

[I am following this tutorial](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/docker/README.html).

Currently there i already another app running on localhost so I changed the ports in docker -compose.

What I currently have: I'm in a directory I created called 'gitlab_test'. I have set a global variable per the instructions `echo $GITLAB_HOME  /srv/gitlab`.

I pulled the ce gitlab image `docker pull store/gitlab/gitlab-ce:11.10.4-ce.0`

Then, in the gitlab_test directory I added a docker-compose file:

```yaml
web:
  image: 'gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest'
  restart: always
  hostname: 'localhost'
  environment:
    GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
      external_url 'https://gitlab.example.com'
  ports:
    - '8080:8080'
    - '443:443'
    - '22:22'
  volumes:
    - '/srv/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab'
    - '/srv/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab'
    - '/srv/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab'
```

I am unsure if I need to put 'localhost' in place of hostname and external url parameters. I tried that and as is and in each case I cannot see anything happen. I was expecting a web interface for gitlab at localhost:8080.

Tried `docker-compose up` and the terminal ran for a while with a bunch of output. There's no 'done' message (perhaps because I did not use -d?) but when I visit localhost:8080 I see no gitlab interface.

How can I run the gitlab ce container?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use different port you should not change your "container port". Only the host port you  are exposing your container port to. So instead of:

```yaml
  ports:
    - '8080:8080'
    - '443:443'
    - '22:22'
```

You should have done:

```yaml
  ports:
    - '8080:80'
    - '443:443'
    - '22:22'
```

Which means you expose the internal container port `80` (which you cannot change) to your host port `8080`.

**UPD:** I started this service locally and I think there are few things except ports to consider.

1. You should create `$GITLAB_HOME` folders (by this I mean that there is no need to register environment variable but rather to create set of dedicated folders). You take this `'/srv/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab'` from example but this basically means "take content of `srv/gitlab/config` and mount it to the path `/etc/gitlab`" inside the container. I believe the paths like  `/srv/gitlab/config` do not exist at your host.
2. Taking the above in the account I would suggest to create a separate folder (say `my-gitlab`) and create the folders `config`, `logs` and `data` inside that folder. They are to be empty but will be filled on Gitlab start.
3. Put your `docker-compose.yaml` to `my-gitlab` and switch to that folder.
4. Run `docker-compose up` from that folder. Do not use `-d` flag so that you're not detaching and can see if errors happen.

Below is my `docker-compose.yaml` with some explanation:

```yaml
web:
  image: 'gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest'
  restart: always
  hostname: 'localhost'
  environment:
    GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
      external_url 'http://localhost'
  ports:
    - '54321:80'
    - '54443:443'
    - '5422:22'
  volumes:
    - './config:/etc/gitlab'
    - './logs:/var/log/gitlab'
    - './data:/var/opt/gitlab'
```

**Explanation:**

- I have my local services running at `80`, `8080`, `22` and `443` so I expose all the ports to what I have free by the moment
- At this part `http://localhost` the `http://` is important. If you set `https://` Gitlab attempts to request SSL certificate for your domain at *Letsencrypt*. To make this you have to have public domain and some sort of port configuration.
- Volumes are mounted through `.` (current directory) so that it is important to have consistent structure and call `docker-compose up` from a proper place.

So in my case I could successfully connect to `http://localhost:54321`.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I've updated the ports now but still cannot connect "We can’t connect to the server at gitlab.example.com.". I tried changing external_url to 'localhost' but then got error "GitLab external URL must include a schema and FQDN, e.g. http://gitlab.example.com/"

Comment: See my updates where I mention couple of important points.