# Gitlab test out with Docker: ' You have signed up successfully. However, we could not sign you in because your account is awaiting approval...'

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab

I have set up gitlab locally on ubuntu laptop per some help from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65169038/hello-world-with-gitlab-ce-docker-container-running-on-local-ubuntu) post. My set up is 100% exact to per that post. When I ran `docker-compose up` and visited localhost:54321 I was shown a screen to 'update my password'. I entered a new password then got taken to the sign in page where I clicked to sign up with a new account. I entered my name, email and password and hit register. I then saw this message:

[image]

I'm confused since I'm hosting gitlab locally via docker.Who is my gitlab administrator?!

How can I register on a locally hosted gitlab instance via docker? My ultimate goal is just a hello world - I'd like to explore the gitlab interface and see what the tool is all about.

Comment: On first start, the password is set for user `root` Use that username and the password to get in. Then go to the admin area and create the user accounts you need. You can also allow user registration without approval if you need. Else you will be able to approve registrations with an admin account.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the info. On my laptop I login with my username doug and doug is sudo. Is that the equivalent for root? I tried logging in with my regular login details user: doug, pass: $mypass as well as user:root: pass: $mypass. In both cases I got an 'invalid login' error message. Can you clarify what you mean by root?

Comment: Reading this post, looks like Ubuntu doesn;t set a pw for root :/    https://askubuntu.com/questions/189907/what-is-the-default-root-password

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The initial admin user for the GitLab CE is `root`.
In the GitLab Docker container path /etc/gitlab, there will be a file called "initial_root_password". Cat the content and you can got the initial password of the user `root`

Steps:
Assume the docker container name is `gitlab_web_1`

1. Go to the Docker container: `docker exec -ti gitlab_web_1 /bin/bash`
2. List item: `cat /etc/gitlab/initial_root_password`

Once you login with the user `root` successfully, you can try to manage the user account, and you can also use your own account to login.

Answer (score 1):

Based on This Page

```
https://forum.gitlab.com/t/after-gitlab-ce-installation-on-ubuntu/32896
```

Username and Password default Administrator after Install Gitlab-ce:

Username: root

Password: 5iveL!fe

Answer (score 0):

When opening the web interface after first running the container, you are prompted to 'change password'. Enter a password then on the next page enter username 'root' and the password you just created. I had to rerun the container and first empty everything in the set up directories. Emptied everything in data/, logs/ and config/ and then `docker-compose up`. That allowed me to login